# efficiency and speed increase of invoke-parallel -scriptblock

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a method to speed this command up and make it use resources more efficiently?

I am willing to convert to python 3.5 if the files do not have to be extracted and can be parsed via evtx file format.

I have a script i am running with the cmdlet invoke-parallel with a script block. The $files is a listing of 10000 evtx files I am filtering based on username and event ids.

I have attempted to call a new instance of powershell.exe and run the get-winevent cmdlet from the scriptblock but this instantiates to many processes without closing out. I have not tried jobs but am unsure as to where to do so in this instance.

```
$files | Invoke-Parallel -ImportModules -ScriptBlock{ 
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$_;id=4624;data="ANONYMOUS LOGON","user.name1", "user.name2" } | 
    Select-Object  -Property MachineName,RecordId, TimeCreated,Id,
    @{Name="SubjectUserSid"; Expression={$_.Properties[0].Value}},
    @{Name="SubjectUserName";Expression={$_.Properties[1].Value}},
    @{Name="SubjectDomainName";Expression={$_.Properties[2].Value}},
    @{Name="SubjectLogonId";Expression={$_.Properties[3].Value}},
    @{Name="TargetUserSid";Expression={$_.Properties[4].Value}},
    @{Name="TargetUserName"; Expression={$_.Properties[5].Value}},
    @{Name="TargetDomainName";Expression={$_.Properties[6].Value}},
    @{Name="TargetLogonId";Expression={$_.Properties[7].Value}},
    @{Name="LogonType";Expression={$_.Properties[8].Value}},
    @{Name="LogonProcessName";Expression={$_.Properties[9].Value}},
    @{Name="AuthenticationPackageName";Expression={$_.Properties[10].Value}},
    @{Name="WorkstationName";Expression={$_.Properties[11].Value}},
    @{Name="LogonGuid";Expression={$_.Properties[12].Value}},
    @{Name="TransmittedServices";Expression={$_.Properties[13].Value}},
    @{Name="LmPackageName";Expression={$_.Properties[14].Value}},
    @{Name="KeyLength";Expression={$_.Properties[15].Value}},
    @{Name="ProcessId";Expression={$_.Properties[16].Value}},
    @{Name="ProcessName";Expression={$_.Properties[17].Value}},
    @{Name="IP"; Expression={$_.Properties[18].Value}},
    @{Name="IpPort";Expression={$_.Properties[19].Value}}} -throttle 100 |
     Export-Csv -path "C:\users\username\Desktop\folder\full.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a ~50x speed-up of single job as measured on my main security audit eventlog file (20MB).

The problem with your code is caused by the standard PowerShell stuff which is terribly inefficient in case of large amounts of data.

- Select-Object with 20 calculated properties creates 20 ScriptBlock contexts for each record. Context creation in PS takes a lot of time compared to the actual simple code inside.
- Get-WinEvent creates custom objects for each event with 20+ NoteProperty objects inside,
  each takes time to create.
- Export-CSV needs to access each NoteProperty then in addition to using the slow PS pipeline
- `|` pipelining is slower than flow control statements such as foreach (not cmdlet), while.

Let's get dirty and do everything manually using .NET 3.5+ and PS3+:

```
$CollectLogonsInCsv = {
param(
    [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -literal $_ })]
    [string]$eventLogPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]$users,

    [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -IsValid -literal $_ })]
    [string]$outputPath = ($eventLogPath -replace '[^.]+$', 'csv')
)
    $query = '*[System/EventID=4624 and EventData[' +
        ($users -replace '^.+', 'Data[@Name="TargetUserName"]="$&"' -join ' or ') + ']]'
    $reader = [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader]::new(
        [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogQuery]::new($eventLogPath,
            [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.PathType]::FilePath, $query)
    )
    $writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputPath, $false, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8, 16MB)
    $writer.WriteLine('MachineName, RecordId, TimeCreated, Id,' +
        'SubjectUserSid, SubjectUserName, SubjectDomainName, SubjectLogonId, ' +
        'TargetUserSid, TargetUserName, TargetDomainName, TargetLogonId, ' +
        'LogonType, LogonProcessName, AuthenticationPackageName, WorkstationName, ' +
        'LogonGuid, TransmittedServices, LmPackageName, KeyLength, ' +
        'ProcessId, ProcessName, IP, IpPort')
    while ($e = $reader.ReadEvent()) {
        $p = $e.properties
        $writer.WriteLine('"' +
            [string]::Join("`0",
                $($e.MachineName, $e.RecordId, $e.TimeCreated, $e.Id; $p[0..19].value)
            ).replace('"', '""').replace("`0", '","') + '"'
        )
    }
    $writer.close()
    [GC]::Collect()
}
```

Now invoke it in parallel using RunSpaces for further improvements:

```
$outputDir = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder\4768'

Get-Content C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\fullfiles.csv |
    Invoke-Parallel -throttle 100 -ImportModules -ImportVariables -ScriptBlock {
        $outputCsv = Join-Path $outputDir ((Get-Item -literal $_).BaseName + '.csv')
        & $CollectLogonsInCsv $_ @(
            'user.name.1'
            'user.name.2'
            'user.name.3'
            'user.name.4'
        ) $outputCsv
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look into setting up [Runspaces and RunspacePools](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/26/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/).  They are a bit tricky to set up, but they are very cool and very efficient in the way that they work.  The pools allow you to set a throttle of sorts. The RunspaceFactory loads a job into 1 of x slots, then once one finishes it tosses another in that slot.
One of the **big** advantages to this is the overhead - or lack of overhead, rather.  Runspaces don't require another instance of PowerShell, whereas Jobs do.

So, if you have a RunspacePool with a width of 50 and 1000 jobs to process, 50 of those jobs will be running at any one time.  Super cool.

[Check out this example from mjolinor](https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/invoke-scritptasync-v2/).
Granted, that is a pretty complex example.  He's gone through a lot of trouble to gain access to the various data streams.  That makes monitoring the processes in the pool possible.